# Naturally-ocurring Airborne Floating Islands - is it possible?

Tags: geology

So, on a previous question of mine, someone answered [that it would be feasible to build a city on a waterborne floating island using a pumice layer below the ground](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/64252/ferrying-an-island-with-mortals-on-top-is-it-possible-without-killing-them).

That got me thinking about the possibility of having a city built on a floating island, but airborne.

Now, I know that there have been questions about floating islands already... but those implicated major geological catastrophes projecting rocks into the air, technological or magical human intervention and atmospheric gases different than our own.

But my question is different: Is it possible to conceive of an imaginary rock that would float on the air of an Earth-like atmosphere, some distance above the ground? I know this seems impossible, but having a rock that floats on water also seems impossible and we have pumice.

I don't want real world examples (they don't exist), only to know if such a rock could be theoretically possible. A geological material that could form floating islands in the sky where the building of cities would be possible.

Comment: Pumice floats on water because it contains pockets of air. To get a rock to float on air, it would need to contain pockets of something much less dense than air. Maybe that's a starting point?

Comment: If your island had a big block of superconducting material inside (and more in the ground) it's entirely possible that it would float in the air, although I can't say how high you'd be able to get before the effects diminished (magnetic fields and the inverse square law and all that)

Comment: @Samwise: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Superconductors have an innate ability to *strongly* repel any and all magnetic fields from their interior, this means that when a mass of super conductor moves over a magnetic field, not only will it be lifted into the air, it can even be *locked in place* as if by some invisible force field (it's called "flux pinning") [here's a good video demonstrating the effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPqEEZa2Gis)

Comment: @Samwise: What do you say to Molot's answer below regarding superconductors?

Comment: It *IS* true that no known room temperature superconductors exist but seeing as there was no "reality-check" or "hard-science" tags, I didn't think it mattered (superconducting rocks was the basis for the floating mountains in *Avatar*). As for permanent magnets not "holding their magnetism for too long", I can't say I've heard that before, depends on what "long" means, you can go out to the Pilbara in Australia and find magnetic rocks that are quite old (they're not too potent though)

Comment: Check out [Gulliver's Travels to Laputa](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/829/829-h/829-h.htm) (part III).

Comment: @Mołot either that, or that it has all flown into the sun, or out of the solar system :D

Comment: @MarkGardner that's not how it works. Atmosphere gets thinner the higher you go, and at some point you reach point where your buoyancy is 0.

Comment: @Mołot not if your weight is negative.
Alternatively, they might have hung around, and been smashed by meteors

Comment: @MarkGardner Negative mass is pure fantasy, as far as physics knows it.

Comment: To add to Mołot's answer - magnetic lift solution is difficult, but not scientifically impossible. Your "imaginary rock" would be "Unobtanium" from the movie "Avatar". P.S. Oh, I see, Samwise already beat me to it.

Comment: I read the Edge Chronicles a while ago and remember there being a floating city. This might help: http://theedgechronicles.wikia.com/wiki/Flight-Rocks As was previously suggested, flight rocks have pores everywhere.

Comment: Why is this question not a duplicate of http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/123/what-could-cause-rock-formations-small-stones-boulders-islands-to-levitat ?

Comment: Related and potentially useful info here:  http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27627/i-would-like-a-levitating-temple-on-a-mountain-hand-wave-free-ish

Comment: Do you truly not believe the reason real-world examples don't exist is that such rocks are no more theoretically than really possible? Following what research you've done, what would a geological material that could form floating islands in the sky where the building of cities would be possible be like?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Consider a biological 'assist'**

You have your chunk of pumice-like rock, with plenty of pores, holes, and tunnels.  Within these is a thriving bacteria.  The bacteria is particularly attractive to a fungus that can grow without direct sunlight.

The fungus' output is a gas that fills a bladder or bubble within it.  This gas is lighter than air and as the fungi fill the bladder, it begins to lift the soft-stone structure slowly until it reaches a certain atmospheric pressure.  At the equivalent of 5,000m, the gas is equal with the atmosphere and the island stabilizes with respect to altitude.  This does not mean it will stay still.

**Limitations**

*You will still have a lot of wind.*  Do you want this?  You can have a community develop on the 'island' whose weight presses it down, and the response of the gas-bladders lift it back to that level.  However, winds will push it every which way at the 5,000m altitude.

You can run into things.  The choice of 5,000m is somewhat suitable for humans.  However, this is roughly the altitude of base camp for Mt Everest, so there may be mountains struck.  **Your next question could focus on how to stabilize your now-floating mountain.** I look forward to that.

EDIT with ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: I am not sure your intended use of the island or the type of city you want, but a city [might weigh 10m tons](https://www.quora.com/Can-someone-tell-me-how-heavy-a-city-is-and-how-it-affects-the-earth).  I am going to go with a compact, radial city, in order to address your question although there is a LOT of speculation and variables.

[image]

Warm gas like methane filling sacs within your fungi will lift the city until it reaches equilibrium with the atmosphere at around 500m height.  This means that even if the fungi continue to produce more gas, your city will max out at around 500m.  The weight of your city presses down, but your CH4 -filled fungi press up.  Atmospheric conditions are not stable, so there will be a lot of ups and downs - make sure your denizens and engineers are comfortable with that.

Note: I am not an artist / Note2: There are too many unknowns for precision math, but this could work for your story at a minimum.

Comment: Great answer, and very imaginative! Thank you! However, do you have anything that would address Molot's objection, that using floating gas would mandate very thin walls on the rock, that would burst out with high altitude pressure?

Comment: As for my next question regarindg this topic, it would rather have to do with survival. My floating civilization would not be very high tech and 5.000 m altitude is, AFAIK, above rain clouds that should be the main watersource. As for stability, I was leaning on using a series of air drogues / anchors.

Comment: You could lower the height to whatever you like - I just picked an upper altitude for human comfort.  If you wanted it to be 1,000m or whatever, you could do that.  It was an arbitrary number.  However, as you get lower to the ground, the air pressure is less uniform, so you'd likely want to keep it at least 500m+.

Comment: @PedroGabriel - I think the bladders on the fungi can be extraneous to the pumice rock; that is to say, they are outside of your soft rock, so they can be as varied and populated as much as you like on the outside of the rock.  The gas should meet equilibrium of the atmosphere at the elevation you prefer.  So even if you have a million extra fungi sacs, if they're equal at the height you prefer, it is okay: just more stabilization.

Comment: Won't the rock fracture before it can lift.. it'll be too weak to contain the high pressure gas which could lift it

Comment: @Innovine - Then the OP can consider a denser stone that is latticed throughout.  I would caution against some very light stone, which erode quickly with rain, and some igneous rocks, which are extremely heavy.

Comment: @mikey denser stone means heaver, meaning even higher pressure before it will lift. Stone isn't strong enough to contain lighter-than-air gas capable of lifting it. Its one reason why we don't make stone balloons

Comment: @Innovine - exactly; the stone isn't doing the lifting.  The air sacs are doing the lifting of the stone.  The softer the stone, the easier to lift; but also the easier to erode, so a balance needs to be met.

Comment: @PedroGabriel - Can you specify (as an edit) the elevation you want to achieve and some details about the city you expect?  It's hard to make the best answer without this information.

Comment: What form would the island need to have, to keep it from flipping?

Comment: @TheSexyMenhir - definitely inverse-conical, bearing the greatest load in the center.

Comment: Taking "biological assist" and running with it: You could instead have trees which form gas-filled balloons due to a biological process that produces hydrogen as a by-product. Instead of expelling the gas, the tree contains it in "balloons" so the lift can help support its own weight so it would not require such a large trunk, and an evolutionary cue that if it expelled H2 over millennia in the atmosphere a single spark could set the planet ablaze. The tree evolves a thinner trunk until with erosion the roots actually lift small rocks off the ground. Solves larger volume than rock can contain

Comment: @ITBear - Hey that's a good idea, because in addition to the fungi below, the trees above could provide stability above, particularly because the majority of them would be found on the periphery of the city (small forestland).  A ring of 'load-lifting' trees could help keep the city even.  I'd steer away from H2 being their product, though haha

Comment: @Mikey: Sorry for the late answer, for my computer broke. As for your query, I've asked a separate question here: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/70404/optimal-height-for-an-airborne-floating-island

Comment: You guys are WAY overestimating the lifting power of any possible lighter than air gas; as one of the answers below point out, you get about a kilogram per cubic meter of gas. So imagine a 1km balloon for every ton of city. (not including the island)

Comment: @Seeds - this is specifically not a "hard-science" question for that very reason.  The user wants a story-telling / world-building rationale for a floating island, so a fictional type of lighter-than-air gas and a fictional amount of space underneath the city/island is the only way to make this storyline work.

Comment: While I did notice the lack of a hard science tag, the question ALSO asked if it were theoretically possible, to which the answer is NO. The only way to make it work is with anti-gravity rock. Air doesn't weigh enough.

Comment: @Seeds - good point.  I should maybe edit the answer to say it is theoretically true with a gas similar to methane in properties, but with a larger ability to lift.

Comment: The absolute best any gas can do, without antigravity/magic properties, is the difference between it's weight and the weight of the air it displaces. So a balloon filled with vacuum would be as good as it gets (sans magic/antigrav)  which is only good for about 1.2 g/L  lift at sea level on Earth.

Answer (score 12):

Not really. You would need a porous rock filled with hydrogen or helium. Hydrogen can lift bout 1.1 kg per cubic meter of its volume. This means you would have to have about 1kg of rock holding 1 m³ of gas. This means bubbles would need to have really, really thin walls.

Now, thin walls are not out of the question. No problems when pressures are equal. But then your rock would rise from were it formed. Up there, pressure is lower. Thin walls and pressure difference would make bubbles burst, release hydrogen. And all you get is shattered pumice.

---

For magnetic lift, there is another problem. Permanent magnets don't hold its magnetism for too long, and no known substance could keep superconductivity at outdoors temperatures — as far as we know now. Our knowledge of superconductivity was shattered few times and we have superconductors so hot that 20 years ago we *knew* it's impossible, but then, now we can only speak from the point of view of the knowledge we have now — and superconductive pinning without power supply doesn't seem possible nowadays.

Comment: A room-temperature super conductor and an abnormally strong magnetic field would do the trick. Just because we haven't seen one doesn't mean they're not possible.

Comment: The big problem with magnetic lift is that *you can't have lift with permanent (passive) magnets alone*. It's a consequence of Earnshaw's Theorem, and the usual loopholes (using also diamagnetic materials, or active controls) aren't applicable here.

Comment: LSerni, could you please explain why diamagnetic (or superconductive) levitation is not applicable here?

Comment: @Alexander, sorry hadn't seen the comment - that's because we want *passive* operation, and passive magnetic levitation is simply not possible. However cleverly you place your magnets, the configuration will always be unstable. You need some stabilizing effect apart from simple gravity, and that must be active - be it a gyroscope, a PLL, ultrasonic feedback. The only "passive" means would be *chains* fettering the island to the ground. Finally, diamagnetic stabilization would require a magnetic source and a thick shield of e.g. bismuth *above* the island.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine an extremely fibrous vine. Now imagine that this vine likes to grow on pumice, which it roots deeply in. Finally, imagine that this plant's metabolism, somehow, produces an excess of hydrogen, which it stores in hollow leaves. Since the vine gets no nutrients from the roots anyways, it would not be limited in length. Its strength could be due to structures similar to carbon nanotubes.

Not exactly a floating rock, but scientifically plausible. And, by putting the buoyant gas-bag above the low-density rock, you avoid the problem of building on top of the rock causing it to flip over.

Answer (score 3):

## Option 1: The solar system design

Why can't you have a small scale solar system as a planet? 
If you thought of our solar system as one planet, it would be very similar to what you're requesting. 
Instead of having a crust, I don't see why a planet couldn't be straight core... with no inhabitable land mass attached to the actual planet. From here, all the "islands" are just land masses that are in a low orbit around the core.

As for an atmosphere, the ISS is technically in the earth's atmosphere, so there are basically 3 options.

1. Having your inhabitants capable of surviving in an EXTREMELY low atmosphere environment, meaning that they don't have the same gas requirements as anything remotely human. 
2. Designing the base planet to have an incredibly strong atmosphere, that would be too dense for long-term living at the surface, but be perfect for living on the fringe, where the orbiting islands are. 
3. Give each orbiting island it's own atmosphere, limiting inter-island travel, but being easy to communicate to readers.

---

## Option 2: The helium generator

This one's a bit of a stretch, but if you have a very small nuclear fusion reactor (read star) at the middle of each island, which had branches/corridors running through the island, you would have an island lighter than air, but you would need an incredibly air-tight center, and the island would have to be long and flat.

---

## Option 3: The dense atmosphere

We all know that tungsten hexafluoride is the densest gas, at about 13 grams / liter, and we should all be familiar with aerogel, the solid made out of silicon dioxide and air. In theory, a large enough island, composed primarily of aerogel, or something similar, could work when sitting on top of an "ocean" of tungsten hexafluoride. This would look like boats of light solids on top of heavy gasses, which could work.

---

## Summary

As far as I know, all of these are plausible, if not extremely rare. They are also all longterm, meaning you don't have to be worried of magnetism fading, etc. I like option 1 the best, but in a properly engineered system, all of them would work. From a purely dynamic standpoint, option 3 would be the closest analog to a boat (read floating island) as it would be an actual platform resting on what it perceives as a solid base, as opposed to counting on some other property (orbit/lift) to maintain the floating aspect of the island.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Note that the first option couldn't work: atmospheric drag would slow and then stop the islands unless they had ways to propel themselves - the main physical different between islands and space stations. While I love your third option, the OP also said they weren't interested in `atmospheric gases different than our own`. Still, creative, and welcome!

Comment: being an atmosphere half full guy, I don't see why the atmosphere couldn't be half tungsten hexafluoride, aka what the island was sitting on, and the top half be a mixture similar to ours... as to the first option, subsection 3 might be the best variant on option 1... but I feel it could work if the inhabitants could live on extremely low atmospheric pressures... as in like... ISS atmospheric levels. But thanks for the welcome! I like it here, the community is very nice, and the questions are incredibly thought provoking

Answer (score 2):

## Not naturally, but yes. And for gengineered values of "natural"...

You can have [substances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerogel) quite resistant and lighter than air, but not by very much. [Evacuated aerographene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerographene) has about 16% air density, and can withstand considerable pressure. Every cubic meter of aerographene can lift about 800 grams in air. You can cover it with air-tight silicon or graphene foil, so that it *stays* evacuated, reducing its buoyancy to about half a kilogram. Non-evacuated aerographene is *heavier* than air and would sink.

The reason why we fill balloons with hydrogen instead of vacuum is that we need *something* inside to counteract the outer air pressure and prevent the ballon from collapsing with a thunderclap. But if the "balloon" is filled with aerographene, that is enough. Actually, an even lower "density" can be achieved with a *hollow* evacuated aerographene ball (spherical to better withstand the pressure) with an airtight outer shell. But there would be air between the balls, so every cubic meter would be about [25% air if we use equally-sized balls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres), 75% hollowed aerographene and some shell material. On the other hand, the material resistance is high enough that we might be able to use hollowed-out cubes instead of spheres.

But we're pushing against an absolute lift limit of one kilogram per cubic meter (the lifting power of vacuum), so we'll hit the point of diminishing returns pretty fast.

Small spheres would have the advantage of being manufacturable by biological constructs (you'd need impressive genetic engineering skills). You could cultivate (or mine) the *spheres of levity* and believe they're *natural*.

To be able to lift one ton per square meter, the "island" would need to be at least two kilometer deep. Actually more than double than that, because you want to have more mass as ballast *below* the island than *above*, or the island will tend to capsize. Also, "upper" air will be less dense and provide less buoyancy.

If you're willing to have a thinner upper crust and employ a lot of aerogel for the upper buildings, and use flimsier sealants in the island's core, you can have [a reasonably thin floating island](http://orig08.deviantart.net/0e97/f/2015/045/3/0/floating_island_by_tiga1122-d8hyz2h.png). Which brings us to the problem of *steering* it and surviving storms and the like.

Comment: I really like the idea of mining "spheres of levity". That's an amazing pun combining "levitation" and "humor or frivolity, especially the treatment of a serious matter with humor or in a manner lacking due respect."

Answer (score 2):

For a naturally ocurring floating island, we need a naturally ocurring:

- A lighter than air gas (methane, near vacuum ambient air)
- A membrane impermeable to gases ( [guanine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swim_bladder) like in swim bladders, [fullerene](http://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms7212), ...)
- A material strong enough to resist the pressure differences (to avoid implosion or explosion) like diamond, fullerenes, ...

What could have happened is that similar to the diamond formation process, a rock made of carbon nanotubes imprisons bubbles of very hot air under very high pressures deep down in the mantle of the planet (bubble diameter varying from mm to m of diameter).

As these rocks move up to the crust, they cool down and the carbon based material solidifies and imprisons the gases. As the gases cool down, it turns the inside of the `bubble` into an effective void.

In the process, they would collect ammonia rich materials (more on this later).

Billions of years later those rocks reach the surface and the local sapient specie(s) notice that a certain rock, if let free from the other rocks, will float. If caught in nets, they make it very easy to carry heavy loads over long distances.

As extraction progress, dear devils from the younger generations start experimenting climbing on the bigger rocks and playing with floating and how to direct the rocks with artifact. At some point they will realise that what used to be a problem for their parents (breaking the rocks makes them fall) can be used to avoid going too high, they might even master how to do it to control rising / falling.

Then someone will notice that a rock which was burst with a small crack can be made to float again if filled with ammonia gases.

Because of the huge amount of naturally occurring ammonia, they would have developed a rudimentary absorption fridge [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_refrigerator), then a local equivalent of Da Vinci will design a way to control the amount of ammonia which goes into those huge balloons made with this very light material (basically a huge bubble burst but the rest of the material still contains a lot of small bubbles so it is still very light) and thus adjust the floatability of the system. Attaching those ammonia filled balloons to the 'almost' floating island will allow them to float and control altitude.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it might be possible.It can be achieved in two ways.

1. **Uing quantum levitation**

   If the island is somehow locked into its position by quantum levitation effect against the earths magenitic field it can stay in the air.But considering the weak force of the earths magnetic field when compared to the earths gravity this might be hard to achieve such effect.

> If you had a really really big magnet, whose field extended over such a large region that the Earth’s field changes noticeably over that region (you might need another Earth-sized bar magnet), then yes, a noticeable force can be produced.

this [link](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=1027) explores that option indepth

2. **Antigravity from Supergravity**

   Antigravity like effect could be achieved can be achieved from supergravity called as **unified supersymmetric point-particle quantum field theory**.

> Some particular versions of this theory not only contain the "usual" atractive graviton, a spin-2 particle, but in addition a so-called graviphoton is predicted (1). This graviphoton is a spin-1 vector field, interacts with mattar at the normal gravitational strength, and behaves generally like a massive photon. The fun thing about it is that it can give rise to attractive and repulsive forces. The repulsive forces feature can in principle give rise to anti-gravity effects.

these links explore these option indepth

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/60349/40095
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269379904635

If anyone of the above effects occur in nature then there possibility of natural floating island.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

### Islands floating on liquid

On geological timescales, things crumble, especially large things. This is why you don't actually see islands of pumice, and there's no large patches of pumice floating about. In the end, the pumice crumbles: the gas escapes, the rock sinks.

Now, given the right circumstances, some freak vulcanic eruptions or something, a large pumice island may form, but given some large waves or strong currents, it will break apart, and eventually it will crumble.

In a more general 'any solid floating on a liquid' sense, over time, and on a large scale, substances arrange themselves on density, the least dense material on top. So, given enough of any solid that's less dense than a liquid, it will generally form a thin layer above that liquid (a bit like the Earth's crust).

However, there is one possibility for solids floating on liquids permanently:
The sweet spot where there's not enough of the solid present on the planet to cover the entire planet in a layer, you'll end up with patches of this solid floating over a liquid planet-sized ocean. Example: islands or rock/sand floating on an ocean of mercury.

### Islands floating on gas

The problem with floating on gas is that there aren't any solids light enough to float on normal air without pockets of gas. But that's where the crumbling comes in again.

#### There are two ways to fix this

**First:**
Denser air. There are some gasses out that that are pretty dense. And you can ramp up the density even further by increasing the pressure at which point light solids might be able to float on (or rather somewhere in, at a certain pressure) the gas. (This [actually is a thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonization_of_Venus#Aerostat_habitats_and_floating_cities)).
Again, you'll have to be in the sweet spot where your solid doesn't just cover the entire planet but forms patches.
But I don't see a planet like this supporting intelligent life.

**Second:**
Counteract crumbling. The only way I can think of is some kind of organism which heals any damage and inflates bladders, like in [Mikey's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/68996/33078).
This actually seems like a decent survival strategy for some micro-organism, to build their own sort of zeppelin and (like pollen) drift in the wind.

These organisms could produce methane (about half as dense as air), or even better: hydrogen (~1% the density of air). All these organisms need are CO2, water, preferrably calcium (from sea-spray?) and some energy source (photosynthesis), they could form some coral-like (calcium carbonate) structure filled with hydrogen bubbles (this would require large bubbles though).

Also, it would help if the atmosphere were a bit denser than here on earth, if the air pressure were 2.5 times the current air pressure, calcium carbonate would *almost* float, so the bubbles can be a lot smaller. A higher air pressure probably also has lots of other implications.

These islands would need to be flat (have a large area for photosynthesis) and probably contain some large cavernous hydrogen pockets somewhere on the inside (potentially formed by decay of calcium carbonate walls on the inside).

Having floating islands of hydrogen filled with hydrogen also opens up the possibility of spectacular [explosions and crashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindenburg_disaster).

Living on an island like this requires very light construction (and/or compensating with hydrogen/helium balloons); not covering too much of the island, as without photosynthesis it would die; only very controlled fires; no drilling; and a good balance to prevent tipping.

Answer (score 0):

Okay; first things first, I'm no geologist, but I think it's not impossible. First of all, you would want an extremely strong and extremely light pumice-like material (some kind of aluminium alloy, maybe?) to build the actual island itself out of, and you would also probably want a fictional gas significantly lighter than hydrogen to fill the internal bubble honeycomb structure.

Comment: Even vacuum isn't significantly better than Hydrogen.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are many answers how could it be possible, but the main question - will it be stable enough to build structures on it? We can imagine some stable point for a floating island, where it will neither rise, nor fall down, at this point it's pretty stable and will not turn other. But each building will add weight, and island will loose it's attitude to the point it won't be that stable, and could turnover.
Also, we DO have a floating rock in our sky. The Moon. The thing is - it's always falling, but constantly misses the Earth.